# Стилизация картинок для выбранных вкладок

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `TabControl`, в котором в каждом `TabItem.Header` есть своя картинка. При выборе вкладки надо чтобы показывалась другая картика (на самом деле идентичная, но в другой цветой гамме). У меня не получается стилизовать инвидуальные `TabItem`, чтобы у них подменялась картинка при выборе вкладки (`IsSelected = true`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, вроде, не сложно:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Height="16">
                    <Image.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Image">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="x.png"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="v.png"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Image.Style>
                </Image>
                <TextBlock Text="Item 1" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Height="16">
                    <Image.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Image">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="x.png"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="v.png"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Image.Style>
                </Image>
                <TextBlock Text="Item 2" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эх, что бы я без вас делал!:)

Comment: Дальше бы в кодбихайнд писали ;)