# Изменение иконки в TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, триггер, treeview

Имеется обычный TreeView. При нажатии правой кнопкой мыши по treeviewitem вылезает меню (добавляет/удаляет запись в/из коллекции). После завершения работы приложения, оно загружает эту коллекцию в xml файл и выгружает его назад при следующем запуске. Так вот, как сделать так, что бы при выполнении этих событий менялась иконка у TreeViewItem? Пробовал сделать через EventTrigger, но не зашло.

И можно ли сделать так, что бы при запуске приложения, все те объекты, которые были сохранены в xml файле снова были отмечены?

P.S. Может есть другой вариант решения этой задачи?

Само дерево.

```
<TreeView Name="tree" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="5,60,100,10">
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding  collection}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image>
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource FolderWithFilesIcon}" TargetType="Image">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource folder}, Mode=OneTime}"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem},                                Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource isSelected}, Mode=OneTime}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Image.Style>
                </Image>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource txtBlockForTreeView}"/>
                    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem x:Name="rightClickPatientSelect" Header="{StaticResource m_selectedPatient}" Click="rightClickPatientSelect_Click">
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem x:Name="rightClickPatientUnSelect"
                            Header="{StaticResource m_unselectedPatient}"                                                          Click="rightClickPatientUnSelect_Click"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                </StackPanel>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding collection}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <StackPanel.Children>
                                    <Image Source="Resources/folder_plus.png" Width="25" Height="25"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource txtBlockForTreeView}" Height="20"/>
                                </StackPanel.Children>
                                    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                                        <ContextMenu>
                                            <MenuItem x:Name="rightClickSelect"  Header="{StaticResource m_conntextMenuSelect}"                                     Click="rightClickSelect_Click">                                                            
                                                <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                    <Image Source="Resources/insertRecord.png"/>
                                                </MenuItem.Icon>
                                            </MenuItem>
                                                <MenuItem x:Name="rightClickUnselect"                                               Header="{StaticResource m_conntextMenuUnselect}"                                                                  Click="rightClickUnselect_Click">
                                                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                        <Image Source="Resources/minus.png"/>
                                                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                                                </MenuItem>
                                            </ContextMenu>
                                            </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                                        </StackPanel>

                                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
<TreeView/>
```

Comment: Ну дык просто имейте в классе, который вы привязываете в TreeView флаг (сохранен/не сохранен, или как там у вас?) и по нему выбирайте картинку

Comment: Мысль уловил, но пример выбора картинки можно. В голову приходит только заполнить панель в коде.

Comment: Примерно как здесь триггером: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/845791/218063

Comment: У меня так первая ветка дерева оформлена. Нужно что бы иконка менялась по событию (при нажатии на menuItem - rightClickPatientSelect).

Comment: И в чем проблема? Устанавливайте с событии свой флаг, а в GUI просто делайте триггер на этот флаг, как в том примере.

Comment: Добавил в класс флаг. Сделал что то подобное:
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:PatientName}, Path=flag}" Value="True">
<Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource isSelected}, Mode=OneTime}"/>
Добавил обработчик:
private void tree_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        { selectedPatientName = e.NewValue as PatientName;
          selectedPatientName.flag = true;}
Меняю флаг в коллекции и ничего не происходит. Где я напортачил?

Comment: Так сложно сориентироваться сразу. Ошибок биндинга нету?

Comment: Была, но она пропала после rebuild'а. С ориентиром всё плохо.